# onMouseMove event stops working after onClick event is called

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my app  when the cursor moves over a div with an image the handleMouseMove event is called. However, after the user clicks over the div the handleMouseMove stops working. I need to move the cursor outside the window to recover the onMouseMove. Do you have any clue about how to solve this? Chat GPT is not helping with this :)

This is the simplified version of my code

```
import React from "react";

const Finder = () => {
  const handleMouseMove = (e) => {
    console.log("handleMouseMove");
  };

  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log("onClick");
  };

  return (
    <div
      onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
      onClick={handleClick}
      style={{ backgroundColor: "red", width: 281, height: 610 }}
    >
      <img
        src="/img/Clothing/ClothingGirl1.jpg"
        style={{
          width: 281,
          height: 610,
          border: "1px solid silver",
        }}
        alt={"alt"}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Finder;
```

Thanks a lot for your help

This is a codepen example: https://codepen.io/Natalia-pamplona/pen/ExMqamY?editors=1111

Comment: Can you create a [mre] where we can see the issue for ourselves? I [can't reproduce](https://jsfiddle.net/0m7p486q/1/) your issue with what you've shared.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have added a codepen example: https://codepen.io/Natalia-pamplona/pen/ExMqamY?editors=1111

Comment: Thanks for the codepen, but I can't reproduce the issue in that either. If I move my mouse over the image, it logs `handleMouseMove` and then when I click, it logs `onClick` and then it continues to log   `handleMouseMove` as I continue to move my mouse over the image.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I haven't been able to reproduce my problem there but I have found the solution. Thanks for your time and your patience

Comment: Nice work, glad you solved it. You should consider adding your solution as an answer if you think it’ll help future readers.